# iframe-resizer, resizing 3 frames in different tabs

Tags: iframe-resizer

I am using iFrameResizer version 3.3.3.

I have 3 iframes set into tabs of a jquery tabs object on a page.
each I frame contains its own tabbed view where the length changes considerably depending on which tab is clicked inside the iframe.

The resizing works perfectly on the a single iframe.

However, on the other 2 iframes (which are on the hidden tabs of the parent page) have their height set to zero and once iFrameResize() as run, the size will not dynamically change.

I have tested this further where I do not run iFrameResize automatically on the page.  each iframe loads with its default size.  If I select the second tab then run iFrameResize from the console, the 2nd tab iframe resizes automatically while the iframes on tabs 1 and 3 have their height set to 0.

Ideally I would like each tab to "activate" its iframe when it is selected and allow the iframe to resize automatically as each of the tabs inside the iframe are selected.  This would be regardless of anything currently selected on any of the other tabs on the parent page.

You can see the above mentioned page at http://brellatech.com.au/iframe.php

Is this possible with iFrame Resizer?

Regards

Greg J

Comment: I don't see any tabs on your link.